# Center icons and text on the same y axis

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to center the text next to the icons but i can't seem to figure it out. What i want to accomplish is something like this.

[image]

However I always get them in the center but not aligned on the same y-axis.

**html**

```
        <div class="profile-info">
        <div class="birth profile-grid">
            <div class="profile-icon"><img src="/images/Iconen/calender-icon.png" alt="" class="birth__icon"></div>
            <p> <span class="birt-date">17/08/2003</span><span class="birth-location">Jette</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="email profile-grid">
            <div class="profile-icon"><img src="/images/Iconen/mail-icon.png" alt="" class="mail__icoon"></div>
            <p>ines.de.backer@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="phone-number profile-grid">
            <div class="profile-icon">  <img src="/images/Iconen/phone-icon.png" alt="" class="phone__icon"> </div>
            <p>+32494031744</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address profile-grid">
            <div class="profile-icon"> <img src="/images/Iconen/location-icon.png" alt="" class="location__icon"></div>
            <p>Dijkstraat 94, 3941Eksel, Limburg</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
        <div class="profile-info">
        <div class="birth profile-grid">
            <div class="profile-icon"><img src="/images/Iconen/calender-icon.png" alt="" class="birth__icon"></div>
            <p> <span class="birt-date">17/08/2003</span><span class="birth-location">Jette</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="email profile-grid">
            <div class="profile-icon"><img src="/images/Iconen/mail-icon.png" alt="" class="mail__icoon"></div>
            <p>ines.de.backer@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="phone-number profile-grid">
            <div class="profile-icon">  <img src="/images/Iconen/phone-icon.png" alt="" class="phone__icon"> </div>
            <p>+32494031744</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address profile-grid">
            <div class="profile-icon"> <img src="/images/Iconen/location-icon.png" alt="" class="location__icon"></div>
            <p>Dijkstraat 94, 3941Eksel, Limburg</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you please share the CSS contents

Comment: Add css instead of html under css section

Answer (score 0):

You could align that those p-items at the bottom. Like change the height to the height of those pictures and make sure its at the same height on the page. Then align at baseline.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution with your current HTML structure using CSS is as follows

```
.profile-grid > * {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```